# How to pass the value of text box and compare it to the variable.. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. How can I display the score when the answer is correct to `<div id="score>` or `<span id="_score>` if the answer is correct?
2. How can I compare the value of my textboxt to value of the results... to I can execute the if else statement

```
<script>

    var points = 0;
    function setVal(){                      
        document.getElementById("_score").innerHTML =points;

    }

    function display(){

        var num1 = Math.round(Math.random()*10 +1);
        var num2 = Math.round(Math.random()*10 +1);

        document.getElementById("_score").innerHTML =points;

        document.getElementById('r1').innerHTML = num1;
        document.getElementById('r2').innerHTML = num2; 

        var result = num1 * num2;

        var answer = document.getElementById('answer').value;

    }


    </script>
```

Comment: So you have the `result` and you want to compare it to `answer` ? Have you tried `===` ?...

Comment: Where is your `if` `else` statement you are talking about ?

Comment: You should check basic tutorials first. There are lot of them out there which can help you learn right from scratch.

Comment: here's my if..else statement    

if(result == answer){
   alert('correct');
  }else{
   alert('WRONG!')
  }

Comment: when i try that.. and i put the correct anser in my textbox.. no alert box show

Comment: Where is your display method called ?

Comment: i called my display function like this

<body onload="display();" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var points = 0;
var correctAnswer;

updatePoints();
init();

//Generate the 2 numbers and calculate the correct answer
function init() {
  document.getElementById("answer").value = "";

  var num1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  var num2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

  document.getElementById('r1').value = num1;
  document.getElementById('r2').value = num2;

  correctAnswer = num1 * num2;
}

//Update the score
function updatePoints() {
  document.getElementById("_score").innerHTML = points;
}

//Check the user's answer with the correct one. If this is correct, score increase.
function validate() {
  var userAnswer = document.getElementById("answer").value;

  if (userAnswer == correctAnswer) {
    alert("Correct !");
    points++;
  } else {
    alert("Wrong !");
  }

  updatePoints();
  init();
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="r1" />*
<input type="number" id="r2" />=
<input type="number" id="answer" />
<button onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
<h1>Score</h1>

<p id="_score"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're out after from your code, but to answer your question about comparing a variable with the value of an input field, take a look at this code:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="answerTextField">
<input type="button" id="answerButton" value="Answer">
```

Javascript

```
var answerTextField = document.getElementById('answerTextField');
var answerButton = document.getElementById('answerButton');

var myAnswer = "5";

answerButton.click(function(e) {
  if(answerTextField.value == myAnswer) {
    alert('Correct');
  } else {
    alert('Wrong answer...');
  }

  return false;
});
```

I have an input field which I compare its value to a value which is stored in the variable myAnswer. The comparison is made when the button is clicked.

I haven't tried the code yet, but it should at least guide you on the way...

Comment: I tried this... and i didint put an onclick="" to my html in button.... and it didn't work... still not showing the alertbox...

Answer (score 0):

```
button.click(function(e) {
  if(answer == result.toString()) {
      alert('Correct');
   } else {
      alert('Wrong!');
   }
   return false;
});
```